# Is it possible to re-create a Windows Recovery Partition after it's been deleted?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

Sometime ago I deleted my recovery partition because my SSD drive was running particularly low on disk space. I removed it figuring I wasn't going to need it.

Unfortunately it turns out that with the Windows 8.1 install disks (from MSDN) apparently it doesn't recognize the current Windows 8 installation and won't let me upgrade.

Is there anyway to re-create the recovery partition and its content from the current installation running? This was a plain Windows install - ie. no OEM customizations/drivers and other crap, just a plain Windows recovery partition from a fresh clean Windows 8 install.

Is there a way to recreate the recovery partition in any way short of a full re-install? I can create the partition easily enough, but is there a way for Windows to create the necessary recovery/version data on that partition?

I haven't found anything online that says you can or can't do this, so I'm looking for a more definite answer here.

Comment: What makes you think the lack of recovery partition is why you can't upgrade to 8.1?